# IIS application pool error while debugging asp.net core 3 web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web API project by choosing default options (weather forecast) using VS 2019 targeting .net core 3.1. I want to host the application in IIS with development support. I am following this
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to host the service in IIS.

However, I get the following error when I hit 'run' selecting IIS profile and debug mode:

[image]

error:

:[image]

Debug properties screenshot:

[image]

IIS AppPool:

[image]

IIS website list:
[image]

event viewer:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the Windows Event Viewer as suggested? What did it say?

Comment: It says: Application pool weatherforecast AppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it startsays 'started'ed a worker process to serve the application pool. Though, I see in my apppool list it says 'started'

Comment: Have you hosted asp.net application in your IIS before? When you need to run .net core application in IIS instead of IIS express. Asp.net core web hosting bundle is required.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out the issue, my app pool was being created automatically with a random password, once I updated that it was all good. As this app pool was running under my username.

Comment: I request you to accept your reply as answer. Thanks